# using coalesce inside case then subquery to get comma seperated values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am wondering if anyone can help me with a problem I've been stuck on for a while. I have a database from where I need to get some data depending upon some variable value, so I tried to do it with a case statement but I'm stuck as there are multiple rows returned by the sub query. Can anyone help me to resolve the issue

This is my current query:

```
Select
   CASE @WorkTypeId
        WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT COALESCE(@GroupId+',' ,'') + CAST(GroupId as VARCHAR(2)) FROM UserGroupRoleMapping
                WHERE UserId= @UserId and IsActive=1 AND GroupId != 4)
        WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT COALESCE(@GroupId+',' ,'') + CAST(GroupId as VARCHAR(2)) FROM UserGroupRoleMapping
                WHERE UserId= @UserId and IsActive=1 AND GroupId = 4)        
        ELSE (SELECT COALESCE(@GroupId+',' ,'') + CAST(GroupId as VARCHAR(2)) FROM UserGroupRoleMapping
                WHERE UserId= @UserId and IsActive=1)
```

the query is for getting all the group in which a user is linked.
like let if work type is 1 and a user with user id 567 is linked with some  groups with group id  1,3,5,4,6 (for each different group there is a new entry in the database) then i need to get all the group ids except '4' which are linked with that user comma separated.

BY using if else i can achieve it by the following query

```
IF  @WorkTypeId =1 
BEGIN
SELECT @GroupId = COALESCE(@GroupId+',' ,'') + CAST(GroupId as VARCHAR(2))
FROM UserGroupRoleMapping
WHERE UserId= @UserId and IsActive=1 AND GroupId != 4
END
```

here i can get the group ids inside the @GroupId variable

Sample data:

```
 UserId   GroupId  WorkTypeId  IsActive 
 567       1          1           1
 567       2          1           1
 567       3          1           1
 567       4          1           1
 567       5          2           1
 567       2          2           1
 567       4          3           1
 567       1          3           1
```

the output which I should get (user id: 567) should be :
when worktypeId=1 
 groupId:(1,2,3) 
when worktypeId=2
groupId :(1,2,3,4,5) 
when workTypeId=3
groupId :(4)
IsActive should be ignore.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Sharing some sample data and the expected result would help make the question much clearer.

Comment: Depending upon the worktypeId ,i need to get some group ids from the db

Comment: by using if else statement i'm able to achieve it but i want to do the same by case statement

Comment: Your last else statement is same as first case statement..

Comment: the values returned by my subquery are more than 1 row so i want to select that values inside the @groupId which i can do in normal query by using coalesce

Comment: @Gauravsa last else statement returns all the values as groupid can be 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE() only if you need to return the first non-null value in a list. EG:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, 'A', NULL, 'B');
```

returns 'A'

Answer (score 0):

You can write your case statement below way and can avoid subquery

```
 SELECT        case when @WorkTypeId = 1 and GroupId != 4 then
               COALESCE(@GroupId+',' ,'') + CAST(GroupId as VARCHAR(2))
               case when @WorkTypeId = 3 and GroupId = 4 then
               COALESCE(@GroupId+',' ,'') + CAST(GroupId as VARCHAR(2))
               else COALESCE(@GroupId+',' ,'') + CAST(GroupId as VARCHAR(2))
               as GroupId
               FROM UserGroupRoleMapping
               WHERE UserId= @UserId
               and IsActive=1
```